# Laravel - Save additional column value to pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, orm, pivot-table

I want to save additional boolean value to to intermediate table in pivot table.
I have models with `belongstoMany` relation. I want to save pivot table **city_school** like this.

But the same value of `is_open` saved for all schools. Only related `is_open` value must be stored for each school_id.

```
city_id | school_id | is_open
   1          1         0
   1          2         1
```

My Models:

**City.php**

```
public function schools()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(School::class)->withPivot('is_open')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**School.php**

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(City::class)->withPivot('is_open')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**View.blade.php**

```
<div>LA<input type="hidden" name="school[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="is_open[1]">Open

<div>SF<input type="hidden" name="school[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="is_open[2]">Open
```

**Controller**

```
$school = $request['school'];
$data->schools()->attach($school, ['is_open' => $request->has('is_open')?1:0]);
```

Comment: In controller: is `$school` the id of the school? Make sure it is. By the way: how can a school be in more than 1 city? Shouldn't it be a one to many relationship?

Comment: `$request->has('is_open')` is always going to be `true`, since it's technically an array. I would think you need to do `$request->has("is_open.{$school}") ? 1 : 0` to get the specific school's status. Actually, if `$request->input('school')` is also an array, you'd have to loop it for `$request->has("is_open.{$school}")` to work...

Comment: @MaartenVeerman I was gonna say the same thing about schools/cities, but it's a terminology thing; I know of the same "school" in multiple cities, but it's because it has multiple "campuses"

Comment: @TimLewis Changing ```$request->has("is_open.{$school}") ? 1 : 0``` gives error ```Array to string conversion```. @Maarten, Yes ```$school``` id is working fine, and logic for cities/school, is the branch of same school in different cities.

Comment: @deep Yeah, see my second note; I didn't see that `$school` is an array of IDs. I think I have a solution, just let me try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$schools` is an array, you'd have to loop and construct what is known as a "syncArray":

```
$syncArray = [];
foreach ($request->input('schools') as $schoolId) {
  $syncArray[$schoolId] = [
    'is_open' => $request->has("is_open.{$schoolId}") ? 1 : 0
  ];
}
```

In the above example, `$syncArray` would contain an array of `$schoolIds`, mapped to an array of "additional attributes", in this case `is_open`:

```
[1 => ["is_open" => 1], 2 => ["is_open" => 0]]
```

Then, you'd simply call:

```
$data->schools()->syncWithoutDetaching($syncArray);
```

And all the records in your pivot table would be updated to reflect what you've passed. Normally, you'd call `sync()`, but that removes anything not within `$syncArray()`, and since this is only updating an attribute, you wouldn't want that.